# How do you get the search query from the DataTable in Shiny R?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Ref : http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-options.html

I want to get access to the search boxes - the global and the column ones to use them in a custom sql query I run on the backend. (I have very limited js knowledge)

Answer (score 0):

For a datatable named `myDT`, the global search bar can be accessed with `input$myDT_search` in a observe block.